# No function when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my code:

```
<head>

<script>input[type=text] {
    padding:5px;
    border:2px solid #000080;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
    border-color:#ccc;
}
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;

}
.rows {
    text-align: center;
}</script>

<script>var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var inpt = document.getElementsByName("post")[0];

function openBox() {
   document.getElementById('postBox').style.display = "block";
}

btn.onclick = function () {

    if (!inpt.value) alert("Please enter something to post.");

    var tbl = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    var row = tbl.insertRow(0);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    var txt = document.createTextNode(inpt.value);
    cell.appendChild(txt);
    tbl.insertRow(0);
    tbl.insertRow(0);

    inpt.value = "";

};</script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="button" name="answer" value="post" onclick="openBox()" />

<div id="postBox" style="display:none;">
<center>
    <input type="text" name="post" maxlength="100" />
    <br>
    </br>
    <button style="border : solid 0px #000080; border-radius : 4px; moz-border-radius : 4px; -webkit-box-shadow : 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0); -moz-box-shadow : 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1.0); box-shadow : 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1.0); font-size : 24px; font-style : ;color : #ffffff; padding : 4px 10px; background-color : #000080;">post</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <center>
    <table class="rows"></table>
</center>
</center>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Everything is fine, but when you go to "post" something, no action is taken, unlike in my JSFiddle below.

My JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/yqh2rqh0/25/) is working perfectly how it is supposed to be working but the web paged version is not.

Comment: are there any errors coming up?

Comment: @jmore009 "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"
and then "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first issue:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

is because your css is being called with `<script></script>` tags instead of `<style></style>`

```
<script> <-------- change to style
input[type=text] {
    padding:5px;
    border:2px solid #000080;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
    border-color:#ccc;
}
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;

}
.rows {
    text-align: center;
}
</script> <----- change to style
```

The second issue:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined
```

is because your javascript needs to be loaded at the bottom of the page right before `</body>` instead of the top in the `<head></head>` (just like your fiddle is loading `No wrap - In <body>)`